# Composer cant install because plugin API does not match composer installation

Tags: laravel, composer-php

Im newbie . Help me.

how could this happen ?

here I will install laravel

```
The "fxp/composer-asset-plugin" plugin was skipped because it requires a Plugin API version ("1.0.0 the "--no-plugins" option. The "fxp/composer-asset-plugin" plugin was skipped because it requires a Plugin API version ("1.0.0 the "--no-plugins" option.
```

I try to back version with

```
composer self-update --rollback
```

and composer ask to update again.

How to update composer with pugins API??

Comment: Please do not post links to images.  It means that others who have the same problem will be unable to find this question and thus benefit from its answers.  You should instead paste the error message directly in the question.

Comment: thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0):

Looks like composer broke api on update and now it cannot run. Try removing global composer vendor dir, which is

`/root/.composer/vendor`

in your case and run the update command again.

Comment: how I can find a vendor dir?

Comment: only erase file fxp in vendor